# Преобразование типов(разница)

Tags: c++

В чем заключается разница в использовании тип_данных(выражение) и (тип_данных)выражение?

Comment: В том, где стоят скобки :) Одно - для С++, второе - для С. А по смыслу - одно и то же...

Comment: В С++ использование и того, и другого является ошибкой.

Comment: Через cast'ы это проводить?

Comment: @VTT, а с каких пор C-style каст стал ошибкой в С++? Вроде бы, его использование **крайне нежелательно** в С++, но ошибкой, насколько я знаю, это не является, разве нет?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker С тех самых пор, когда в С++ добавили специальные средства для разных видов преобразований. Использование C-style cast не является ошибкой в плане валидности кода с точки зрения компилятора (т.е. компилятор не выдает ошибку если не подкручивать опции сборки), но всегда является логической ошибкой.

Comment: @VTT, я прекрасно понимаю, что в С++ добавили специальные касты на все случаи жизни по ряду причин, но фразу "C-style cast'ы - это логическая ошибка" я слышу впервые. Такой каст **может** привести к ошибке, а может и не привести, разве строка `double(100)` несет в себе какую-то логическую ошибку? Да, это **выглядит коряво и Страуструп советовал так не делать**, но тем не менее это не ошибка, а вполне валидный код и с точки зрения компилятора и с точки зрения логики выполнения программы :)

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474933/what-exactly-is-or-was-the-purpose-of-c-function-style-casts

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Ошибка возникает из-за использования средства, мощность которого крайне избыточна для получения желаемого результата при наличии других подходящих средств для его достижения, мощность которых адекватна. Причем эта ошибка возникает независимо от того, получился ли в итоге желаемый результат или нет. При использование C-style cast получается ситуация как в анекдоте: есть назойливая муха, есть мухобойка, но мы загоняем муху под шкаф и отпиливаем ножки.

Comment: @andy.37 Стоит отметить, что тот вопрос был задан еще в 2010 году и большинство ответов уже не отвечает современным реалиям языка.

Comment: Я даже больше скажу, компилятор от Майков ругается и на C++ касты при включении максимального анализа кода.

Comment: @VTT, я уже перестал вас понимать. "Мощность крайне избыточна" и "ошибка" - немного разные вещи в моем понимании. Также не вижу абсолютно ничего плохого с точки зрения логики исполнения в использовании C-кастов для приведения простых численных типов. Что тут "избыточного" я не особо понимаю, да, коряво, да, нечитаемо, да, плохо, но не "неправильно". Если, как вы выразились, человек хочет прибить муху шкафом - это его личное право, да, это корявая логика, но не "неправильная". P.S. на всякий случай прочел пару популярных ответов на eng стэкэ - никто не называет Си-касты ошибкой.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Ну если прибивание мухи шкафом вам не представляется неправильным, то мне нечего возразить... И еще хочу обратить внимание, что я нигде не упоминал ничего в духе "коряво", "нечитаемо", "плохо".

Comment: @VTT, а я и не говорил, что "коряво" - это ваши слова, я таким образом описал нецелесообразность использования си-кастов. Повторюсь, вы - единственный человек, который упорно утверждает, что это именно ошибка, а не "нежелательный способ выполнить определенную задачу". Ну и для закрепления: если для вас это `double(100)` является ошибкой, то мне тоже нечего на это возразить, так что думаю, на этом можно закончить этот диалог :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker *"коряво" - это ваши слова* - еще раз, хочу обратить внимание, что я нигде не упоминал ничего в духе "коряво", "нечитаемо", "плохо". Не надо выдумывать. А при чем тут `double(100)`? Это же не C-style cast (хотя результат получается аналогичный выполнению C-style cast). Собственно в С такого синтаксиса даже не было. Необходимость использования function cast (и вызова конструкторов в круглых скобках вообще) отпала, так как теперь есть list initialization.

Comment: @VTT, вы сейчас на полном серьезе вырвали из контекста мои слова? Сильный аргумент в споре, перечитайте внимательно мои слова: "а я и **не говорил**, что "коряво" - это ваши слова". Если вам так не нравится function cast, "хоть он и делает абсолютно то же самое", давайте я напишу `(double)100`, хоть в С++ есть более подходящие инструменты для каста, Си-каст все равно валиден. Вот эти вырывания из контекста и прочие "аргументы" просто смехотворны, уж извиняйте, мсье, но не вижу смысла с вами спорить, наверное, вам виднее, нежели всему англоговорящему стэку...

Comment: @VTT С тем, что через C-style cast не стоит приводить типы к указателям и ссылкам никто не спорит, по понятным причинам. А что конкретно плохого в приведении к арифметическим типам с его помощью? Все-таки `float(a)/b` намного короче, чем `static_cast<float>(a)/b`. Или вы предлагаете везде использовать C++ casts исключительно для единообразия стиля кода?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну во-первых я не использую длину получившегося кода или единообразие кода в качестве критериев выбора между C-style cast и его альтернативами. А что касается приведения арифметических типов, то использование С-style cast, в этом контексте ничем не будет отличаться от использования его для приведения к указателям и ссылкам. Запись C-stule cast в любом контексте фактически означает требование сделать *любое* подходящее преобразование (или инициализацию), чтобы получить заданный тип из выражения с правой стороны.

Comment: О чем вопрос вообще? Именно от `int`? Или об различии между С-кастами и функциональными кастами вообще?

Comment: @Ant может быть действительно не понятно со словом int, я уже исправил. Конечно же суть заключалась в использовании любого типа данных. Раз непонятен вектор вопроса: я не совсем понимал разницу между двумя примерами кода(которые я привел в вопросе), т.е. в принципе не зная - что один относится к тому-то, другой к тому-то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Единственная разница между `тип(выражение)` и `(тип)выражение` в том, что первом случае имя типа должно быть одним словом, иначе произойдет ошибка компиляции.

Если оба варианта компилируются, то они полностью эквивалентны.

Пример:

```
auto a = int(1);       // ✓
auto b = int*(1);      // ошибка
auto c = const int(1); // ошибка
auto d = long int(1);  // ошибка

auto e = (int)1;       // ✓
auto f = (int*)1;      // ✓
auto g = (const int)1; // ✓
auto h = (long int)1;  // ✓
```

Есть еще `(тип)(выражение)` - это по сути `(тип)выражение`, но со скобками, добавленными к выражению. Между этими двумя вариантами разницы нет совсем (не считая случаев, когда скобки влияют на приоритет операций).

---

> В чем заключается разница в использовании `int(выражение)` и `(int)выражение`?

Так как `int` - это одно слово, для него разницы нет.

---

P.S. `тип(выражение)` не работает в С.

Answer (score 0):

`(double)100` - это преобразование типа (**cast conversion**) в стандарте C. Плюсы такой способ поддерживает.

`double(100)` - стиль плюсов, это вызывает конструктор с преобразованием. Делает то-же самое, называется по разному.

`double{100}` - в **С++11** всё то-же, но следит чтобы не было уменьшения точности.

Comment: А можно просто написать 100.0 (floating point литерал). `double(100)` это function cast, который работает аналогично C-style cast (который тоже может приводить к вызову конструктора). А вот `double{100}` это совершенно другое дело, это direct initialization объекта, не привлекающая C-style cast.

Comment: @VTT Вы очень настойчиво критикуете преобразование типа. Есть два метода: один с аргументом типа **int** , другой **double**. Есть функция, возвращающая **float**. Как методу принимающему **int** передать результат **float** без предупреждений?

Comment: Выполнить `takes_int_or_double(static_cast<int>(returns_flt()))`.

Comment: @VTT Под вопросом вы не ответили, спрошу здесь. Чем конкретно `static_cast<int>(...)` лучше `int(...)`? Не в общем случае (для произвольного типа), а конкретно для арифметических типов.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Погодите минуту, я вам там тоже отвечу...

Answer (score 0):

Конструкция вида `(тип) выражение` называется *C-style cast* (*cast notation*) и служит для преобразования типов в языке С.

Конструкция вида `тип(выражение)` называется *functional cast* (*functional notation*) и было добавлено в С++. Такой синтаксис был полезен в ситуациях, когда получаемый объект не представлял собой значение в него переданное, например `connection("url_string")` (чего не могло быть в С). Существенным моментом является то, что

- `тип` не может быть составным, т.е. запись `long int(1)` невалидна
- `выражение` является опциональным, в таком случае выполняется *direct-initialization*

Разницы в использовании этих конструкций в С++ больше нет, так как для всех сценариев их использования появились альтернативные средства, позволяющие строже соблюдать типобезопасноть, избегать потери данных и точнее выражать намерения. Для преобразования типов служат `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, `const_cast`, и разные специальные функции, такие как `::std::as_const`. Для инициализации следует использовать синтаксис *list initialization* либо встроенные и пользовательские литералы.